# RUN directive in Dockerfile and shellscript file instead fo inline commands, are new layers created?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Inside Dockerfile  I have this

```
......
......
RUN \\
       chown root:root /opt \\
    && chown wasadmin:mqm /opt/adp \\
    && chown wasadmin:mqm -R /opt/adp/pids/ \\
    && chown wasadmin:mqm -R /var/scripts/
.......
.......
```

Instead fo the above I want to put

```
......
......
COPY scripts/myscript.sh /tmp
RUN chmod 700 /tmp/myscript.sh && /tmp/myscript.sh
.......
.......
```

The `/tmp/myscript.sh` has the same contents as that of first RUN command, aka

```
chown root:root /opt
chown wasadmin:mqm /opt/adp
chown wasadmin:mqm -R /opt/adp/pids/
chown wasadmin:mqm -R /var/scripts/
```

By doing the second approach will it reduce layers ?

Comment: The first approach will create 1 layer and the second will create 2. The second image will also contain your script file, so it'll be a little bit larger.

Answer (score 1):

As a practical matter, you will notice absolutely no difference (unless your Dockerfile is very very large) and if the script is substantial you might find it easier to edit and debug the separate script.  If you're considering this path, there's nothing wrong with it.

At a technical level, yes, the "classic" Docker builder will create one additional layer with the extra script.  (The newer BuildKit builder has some optimization capabilities and might behave differently.)  Unless you're hitting Docker's internal layer limit or there are build-cache considerations this doesn't really mean anything.